# SQL Profiler SQL:BatchCompleted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently running a trace to try to find reasons for performance issues I am having using SQL 2005 and have found that SQL:BatchCompleted is only appearing once despite many SQL:BatchStarting events occurring.

Do any of you guys know any reasons for this? If this is a viable reason for the performance issues? if this does prove the performance issues how can it be resolved?

Thanks for any help,

Ric.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to look at the SQL:BatchCompleted events' properties than the ratio of completed events. Some commands take longer to run than others, and it is much easier to isolate them this way.
Once you have isolated the events that take more resources, you can add filters to show only those events, and add the Showplan ALL event. This will give you a good idea what SQL Server is doing.